# Redux-Saga and createAction from Redux-Toolkit does not run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I have been trying to introduce redux-sagas and redux-toolkit to my project. It seems when I `dispatch(fetchTweets(term))` I can see the actions firing off in the Redux DevTools. But when it gets to the saga nothing happens. Not sure how to fix it. Let me know if you have any ideas. Here is the error I am getting. Here is the link to [github](https://github.com/forza11879/twitter-app/tree/master/twitter-app)

[image]

[image]

file - **configureAppStore.js**

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import reducer from './reducer';
import toast from './middleware/toast.js';
import websocket from './middleware/websocket.js';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import tweetSagas from '../saga/tweet.js';

const configureAppStore = () => {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, websocket, toast];
  const middleware = [
    ...getDefaultMiddleware({ thunk: false }),
    ...middlewares,
  ];

  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: reducer,
    middleware: middleware,
  });

  sagaMiddleware.run(tweetSagas);

  return store;
};

export default configureAppStore;
```

file - **saga/tweet.js**

```
import { takeEvery, call, put, fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as actions from '../store/action/saga.js';
const port = process.env.REACT_APP_PORT;
const hostname = process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALHOST;
const baseURL = `http://${hostname}:${port}`;

function api({ dispatch }) {
  return function (next) {
    return function* (action) {
      if (action.type !== actions.sagaApiCallBegan.type) return next(action);
      next(action); // 'sagaApiCallBegan' to show in redux dev tools
      const { url, method, onSuccess, onError } = action.payload;
      try {
        const response = yield call(
          async () =>
            await axios.request({
              baseURL: baseURL,
              url,
              method,
            })
        );
        if (onSuccess) yield put({ type: onSuccess, payload: response.data });
      } catch (error) {
        if (onError) yield put({ type: onError, payload: error });
      }
    };
  };
}

function* watchApi() {
  yield takeEvery(actions.sagaApiCallBegan.type, api);
}

export default function* tweetSagas() {
  yield fork(watchApi);
}
```

file- **store/tweets.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {
  sagaApiCallBegan,
  sagaApiCallSuccess,
  sagaApiCallFailed,
} from './action/saga';
import { webSocketCallBegan, webSocketCallFailed } from './action/websocket.js';
import { normalize } from 'normalizr';
import { tweetSchema } from '../store/Schema/tweet.js';

const initialState = () => ({
  byTweetId: {},
  byUserId: {},
  allTweetIds: [],
});

// action, actionTypes and reducer
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'tweets',
  initialState: initialState(),
  // reducers
  reducers: {
    tweetAdded: (state, action) => {
      const { entities, result } = normalize(action.payload, tweetSchema);
      Object.assign(state.byTweetId, entities.byTweetId);
      Object.assign(state.byUserId, entities.byUserId);
      state.allTweetIds.push(result);
    },
    tweetStoreReseted: (state) => initialState(),
  },
});

export const { tweetAdded, tweetStoreReseted } = slice.actions;
export default slice.reducer;

// Action creators
export const fetchTweets = (term) =>
  sagaApiCallBegan({
    url: `/setsearchterm/${term}`,
    method: 'get',
    onSuccess: sagaApiCallSuccess.type,
    onError: sagaApiCallFailed.type,
  });

export const fetchTweetsPause = () =>
  sagaApiCallBegan({
    url: '/pause',
    method: 'GET',
    onSuccess: sagaApiCallSuccess.type,
    onError: sagaApiCallFailed.type,
  });

export const getTweet = (message) =>
  webSocketCallBegan({
    message: message,
    onSuccess: tweetAdded.type,
    onError: webSocketCallFailed.type,
  });
```

file - **action/saga.js**

```
import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const sagaApiCallBegan = createAction('saga/apiCallBegan');
export const sagaApiCallSuccess = createAction('saga/apiCallSuccess');
export const sagaApiCallFailed = createAction('saga/apiCallFailed');
```

Comment: I think it should be
`export default function* tweetSagas() {  yield fork(watchApi); }`  without the `()` for `watchApi`

Comment: it did fix the error but I still do not get the endpoint from back-end

Comment: Well, your `api` function is not a saga but seems to implement the middleware signature. You're mixing up pretty much anything there.

Just a question: is there a particular reason you're not going with the official recommendation of using thunks and just use `createAsyncThunk`, which would do all of the above in like 5 lines?

Comment: I was able to implement the redux-thunk with redux-toolkit. Now I am trying redux-saga.

Comment: In that case: your `api` function is not a saga. A saga is a generator function, you have two functions returning a generator function and implementing middleware-like behaviour.
If wouldn't really know how to fix that, because that is very far away from anything it should look like. Best revisit the docs on that part yourself.

Comment: posted the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

file - **saga/tweet.js**

```
import { takeEvery, call, put, fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as actions from '../store/action/saga.js';
const port = process.env.REACT_APP_PORT;
const hostname = process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALHOST;
const baseURL = `http://${hostname}:${port}`;

const fetchApi = async ({ baseURL, url, method }) =>
  await axios.request({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    url: url,
    method: method,
  });

function* api(action) {
  const { url, method, onSuccess, onError } = action.payload;
  const options = {
    baseURL: baseURL,
    url: url,
    method: method,
  };
  try {
    const response = yield call(fetchApi, options);
    if (onSuccess)
      yield put({
        type: onSuccess,
        payload: response.data,
      });
  } catch (error) {
    if (onError) yield put({ type: onError, payload: error });
  }
}

function* watchApi() {
  yield takeEvery(actions.sagaApiCallBegan.type, api);
}

export default function* tweetSagas() {
  yield fork(watchApi);
}
```

Comment: You could make this answer a lot more helpful if you explain what you changed and why.